# Border within border CSS

Tags: css, border, css-shapes

With the help of [**CSS Triangle tutorial**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/), I learnt to create triangle shapes.

```
.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;   
        border-top: 20px solid #ccc;
}
```

I'm trying to **add a border to the triangle** but I was unable to do it.

what I achieved:
[image]

**Expected:**(trying something similar border with gray)  [image]

Check this <kbd>[***JSFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/Q97T7/)</kbd>

Stuck up no where to start this.  I tried `outline`, but none worked(I know it won't work).

Thanks for taking time to read my question.

Any help is appreciated.

**Note:** I'm trying this in CSS instead of using images.

Comment: Since you use the borders to actually create the triangle, how do you think you would add **another border**? This technique is more a hack than a legitimate CSS, it works simply because of the way current browsers render border corners.

Comment: @MightyPork Yes I tried from my side.  But you know what I'm trying is a border for the triangle(one side).  A slant line css using before pseudo selector.  Since mmultiple borders is possible I want to try this using css, I don't know some css Geeks can solve it easily.

Comment: are you trying for border only on one side (or) do you want a black border around the triangle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the main triangle or arrow is itself created using the CSS borders, it is impossible to add another border to it without using extra elements. The below are a few options.

**Option 1:** Using a bigger size pseudo-element and positioning it behind the parent to produce a border-effect.

```css
.arrow-down {
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #ccc;
}
.arrow-down:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: -22px;
  top: -20px;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-left: 21px solid transparent;
  border-right: 21px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 21px solid transparent;
  border-top: 21px solid black;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
```

```
.arrow-down:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: -22px;
  top: -20px;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-left: 21px solid transparent;
  border-right: 21px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 21px solid transparent;
  border-top: 21px solid black;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

---

**Option 2:** Rotating the element (which has the border hack to produce the triangle) and then adding a `box-shadow` to it.

```css
.arrow-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-top: 30px solid #ccc;
  -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
  transform: rotate(225deg);
  box-shadow: 0px -3px 0px -1px #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
```

```
.arrow-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-top: 30px solid #ccc;
  transform: rotate(225deg); /* browser prefixes added in snippet */
  box-shadow: 0px -3px 0px -1px #444;
}
```

Tested in Chrome v24 and Safari v5.1.7. Should work in other CSS3 compatible browsers also.

---

> The following options do not directly answer the question as it doesn't do a border within border but are others way of producing an arrow/triangle with a border.

**Option 3:** Using linear-gradients on an element, rotating it to produce the triangle and then adding a border to it using the normal border property.

```css
.arrow-down {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-left: 2px solid #444;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #ccc 50%, transparent 50%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #ccc 50%, transparent 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #ccc 50%, transparent 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ccc 50%, transparent 50%);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; /** <-- to prevent diagonal line aliasing in chrome **/
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
```

```
.arrow-down {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-left: 2px solid #444;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ccc 50%, transparent 50%);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
```

**Option 4:** Using a rotated pseudo-element (with background as the color of the triangle) to produce the triangle and then adding a normal border to it. The parent element's overflow is set to hidden and the pseudo-element is positioned appropriately so as to display only half of it (creating the illusion of a triangle).

```css
.arrow-down {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.arrow-down:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -webkit-calc(100% * -1.414 / 2);
  top: calc(100% * -1.414 / 2);
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #CCC;
  border-left: 2px solid #444;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
```

```
.arrow-down:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: calc(100% * -1.414 / 2);
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #CCC;
  border-left: 2px solid #444;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Comment: +1 I thought that it must be using a `before/ after` pseudo selector.  Hope still there may a wise solution.  Let us wait for that :)  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding these lines to your CSS:

```
.arrow-down:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-left: 26px solid transparent;
    border-right: 26px solid transparent;
    border-top: 26px solid #0f0;
    position: relative;
        left: -26px;
        top: -20px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

This will draw a 3px green border.

Check the result here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q97T7/3/)

Comment: @Harry, you can play with the sizes. Check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/Q97T7/5/

Comment: @Aljullu +1 from my side.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3fFM7/

```
.arrow {
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
    border-left: 60px solid black;
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 0;
    behavior:url(-ms-transform.htc);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
}
.arrow > div {
    border-bottom: 59px solid transparent;
    border-left: 59px solid red;
    border-top: 59px solid transparent;
    left: -60px;
    position: relative;
    top: -63px;
    width: 0;
}


<div class="arrow"><div></div></div>
```

Play with transform rotate :)

Or:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/tKY25/1/

```
<div class="triangle-with-shadow"></div>


.triangle-with-shadow {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.triangle-with-shadow:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background: #999;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   top: 75px;
   left: 25px;
   box-shadow: 0px -5px 0 0px rgba(0,0,0,100);
}
```