# How to create text stroke and triangle with pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to create a `css` design like the image attached below. Actually I need to create this style only using `CSS` without using any images.

[image]

I tried get it to work but not sure How to create inner triangle.

This is my `HTML` -

```css
    body {
      background: #cdc6e1;
    }
    .content-box {
      background: #28166f;
      width: 250px;
      height: 100px;
    }
    .tag {
      background: #f8c300;
      width: 100px;
      height: 0;
      padding-left: 10%;
      padding-bottom: 10%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .tag:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      margin-left: -500px;
      border-left: 500px solid transparent;
      border-right: 500px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 500px solid #f8c300;
    }
```

```html
<div class="content-box">
  <div class="tag">
    <h1>1<span>st</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="name">
    <h1>First<br>
              Place</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope somebody may help me out to achieve to this custom style. 
Thank you.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/TextStroke/

Comment: Part of this question (creation of triangle) is a duplicate of many questions in the css-shapes tag. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057669/border-within-border-css/18058163#18058163) is one sample and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work) is another one. However, I am not voting to close as dupe because this question has another part to it.

Comment: @Harry, Thank you for your comment. Now I have a triangle part work. But see above image it has a one side border of that triangle. Can you tell me how can I get this border? This is my code sofar http://jsbin.com/hoxajulexe/1/

Comment: @user3733831: The first question to which I linked in my previous comment would help you to achieve the border on one side. You can either use an extra pseudo-element (or) box-shadows.

Comment: "I need to create this style only using CSS without using any images." why? CSS is the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: I seem to remember that [Lea Verou](http://lea.verou.me/) has given a few talks about this. May be worth searching for her name on YouTube (or elsewhere).

Answer (score 1):

A basic mockup would be to use some pseudo elements in order to generate this:

```css
.outer {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: purple;
  border: 10px solid pink;
  position: relative;
  text-Align: right;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 200px;
}
.outer:before,
.outer:after {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 100px solid yellow;
  border-right: 70px solid transparent;
  border-left: 70px solid transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 8;
}
.outer:after {
  border-bottom: 130px solid blue;
  border-right: 90px solid transparent;
  border-left: 90px solid transparent;
  z-index: 0;
}
.place {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  color: red;
  bottom: -20px;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: initial;
  z-index: 10;
  
    text-shadow:
    3px 3px 0 white,
    /* Simulated effect for Firefox and Opera
       and nice enhancement for WebKit */
   -1px -1px 0 white,  
    1px -1px 0 white,
   -1px  1px 0 white,
    1px  1px 0 white;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">First Place
  <div class="place">1st</div>
</div>
```

Note. The `text outline` property is yet to be implemented in any of the major browsers yet, so it may require a 'larger white text' to be positioned behind to create this text outline in your mockup.

A workaround (as stateed in the comments) would be to 'hack' the text shadow:

```
 text-shadow:
    3px 3px 0 white,   /* Simulated effect for Firefox and Opera
                       and nice enhancement for WebKit */
   -1px -1px 0 white,  
    1px -1px 0 white,
   -1px  1px 0 white,
    1px  1px 0 white;
```

---

## Text Stroke

---

Although only available in webkit broswers, you may possibly want to use [`text-stroke`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-stroke) for your 'white border' to the text *(unavailable in IE or Firefox)*

```css
div {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  color: black;
}
div:before {
  content: "1st";
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: black;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 8px red;
}
html {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div>
  1st
</div>
<br/>
<strong>Note</strong> only available in webkit browsers
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a duplicate triangle and place it behind. Code given below. JSBin: http://jsbin.com/totewinizu/2/

HTML:

```css
.tag {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 60px 80px 60px;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  z-index: 99;
}
.dupe {
  position: absolute;
  border-color: transparent transparent white transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 60px 80px 60px;
  top: 40px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-box">
  <div class="tag">
    <h1>1</h1><span>st</span>
  </div>
  <div class='tag dupe'>
  </div>
  <div class="name">
    <h1>First<br>
          Place</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```