# Borders on css triangles

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm creating a list of tags made with css only. The have an arrow to the left. However, I would like to add a border all the way around each. How do I add a border to the arrow part?

HTML:

```
<ul class="searchtags">
  <li><a href="#">javaScript</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.searchtags {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.searchtags li,
.searchtags a {
  float: left;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  position: relative;
}

.searchtags a {
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 12px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #4a4949;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
.searchtags a:before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -12px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 12px 12px 12px 0;
}

.searchtags a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  background: #fff;
}
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/3rhh70u2/29/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057669/border-within-border-css/18058163#18058163 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25195526/how-to-create-a-pricetag-shape-in-css-and-html/25195721#25195721

Comment: Yes you are right. That's the solution I didn't find. Thanks.

Comment: Just add a bigger triangle directly below the one you want outlined so as to give the illusion of a border.